# Relative URL not loading PHP file, but exact URL does

Tags: php, apache2

Relevant code:

```php
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/admin/') === 0 ){
    include_once 'admin.php';
    exit;
}

if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'pc-repair-') !== FALSE && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'-computer-services') !== FALSE ){
    include_once 'locations/default.php';
    exit;
}

include_once 'inl/head.php';
```

Example link on site:
`<a href="/about/special-offers/">Special offers</a>`

Trying to make the request to /pc-repair-dallas-tx-computer-services/ but the PHP file doesn't actually load...

PHP is working and short codes are enabled.
I'm not a PHP developer so I'm out of my element here but would appreciate any advice to get these relative URLs working.  They are broken site-wide.  (eg. /about/special-offers/ does not load but /about/special-offers.php does)

So it seems the direction I need to take is a rewrite rule in my .htaccess file.  Now, doing this for each file seems gratuitous, so I'm trying to write a rule that will automatically direct from /page to /page.php.  Here's what I've got so far in my .htaccess

```
php_value short_open_tag 1
Options +MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

EDIT:

***I'm now able to access my files using the desired URL scheme.  The last problem lies within the code at the top, it is not including admin.php when the requested URL is at server.com/admin/***

Comment: What's not loading/working? You mean your `if` condition isn't returning true? What's in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Comment: Accessing the link /about/special-offers/ should return the page /about/special-offers.php but is instead returning nothing.  The REQUEST_URI simply contains the requested URL excluding the server root (eg. google.com/a/b/ is just /a/b/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannon access the `/about/special-offers/` URL and expect your server to return `/about/special-offers.php`, at least unless specifying correct rewrite rules in your .htaccess file. Just use the URL with extension `/about/special-offers.php`.

If you want to avoid using PHP file extensions in your URLs then look for rewriting engine in Apache.

In your specific case, I would make sure the `mod_rewrite` module is enabled on your server configuration and added the following `.htaccess` to the root of your project:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about\/special-offers\/?$ about/special-offers.php
```

Here's the article that might be interesting to you: [mod_rewrite: A Beginner’s Guide to URL Rewriting](https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting-2/)

Comment: This seems to be the direction I need to take.  Thank you.  I'm trying to programmatically solve this and automatically append the .php but am getting a 404 not found.  My .htaccess is ```php_value short_open_tag 1
Options +MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>```

Comment: @JoeHoward Try to remove MultiViews option